# How to expand textfield after a line of words

Tags: android, kotlin

My textfield not expanding after line of words. I can't see my first line after write second line for text box. I want to expand automatically text field. My text field not creating new line after writing words. I can send my message but can't see another lines before send. My language is kotlin.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define input type in text field element .
`android:inputType="textMultiLine"`  and layout height `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Still not solved then please attach your layout XML file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your textview to become flexible, you shouldn't give to it fixed size of
height.
Make its height "wrap_content" so textview's size will change according
to what you write inside it.
Just add:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```